# How to arrange years in order in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
{
2015,
2016,
2017,
2018,
2019,
22/23,
21/22,
20/21,
19/20
}
```

What action do I do so that it displays it in such an orderly manner?

```
22/23
21/22
20/21
19/20
2019
2018
2017
2016
2015
```

Comment: That input data structure is invalid. It's an array not an object, and those elements with `/` need to be quoted because they're strings. Maybe all of the elements should be quoted (for convenience)...?

Comment: You'll probably need to write your own custom sort function that converts those "slash dates" into numbers and returns which of two strings is higher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about input date format, but let's assume that 19/20 means 1920.

You can implement custom sort callback to compare parsed numbers:

```js
const data = [
  '2015',
  '2016',
  '2017',
  '2018',
  '2019',
  '22/23',
  '21/22',
  '20/21',
  '19/20'
]

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
  const parseValue = input => {
    const parts = input.split('/')
    
    if (parts.length === 2) {
      // Convert `19/20` to 1920
      return parseInt(parts[1] + parts[0], 10)
    }
    return parseInt(input, 10)
  }
  
  const result = parseValue(b) - parseValue(a)
  
  if (result === 0) {
    // If equal, add with `/` first
    return b.includes('/') ? 1 : -1
  }
  
  return result
})

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: Ok it works on this array.
What do we do when the array is dynamic and I want it to be in order?
example 
let arr = [
    '2017',
    '22/23',
    '21/22',
    '20/21',
    '19/20',
    '18/19',
    ]

it give me with your code this array 
    '22/23',
    '21/22',
    '20/21',
    '19/20',
     '2017',
    '18/19',

Comment: I am not sure what 18/19 represents -> 1918 year, or 1900 year and 18 month, or something else. If it represents year, algorithm sorts correctly.

Comment: is 2018/2018 ...

Answer (score 1):

Since your input array is invalid...

1. You used object notation (`{}`)
2. The elements with slashes in them are strings and need to be quoted

...here's an example that fixes those errors, and provides you with a sorted array of ascending years.

```js
const arr = [
  2015,
  2016,
  2017,
  2018,
  2019,
  '22/23',
  '21/22',
  '20/21',
  '19/20'
];

// Coerce `a` and `b` to strings and compare
// the last two characters. JavaScript will coerce
// the strings to numbers when it does the comparison.
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return b.toString().slice(-2) - a.toString().slice(-2);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do your own custom sort function. so if your array is like this:

```
var array = [
"2015",
"2016",
"2017",
"2018",
"2019",
"22/23",
"21/22",
"20/21",
"19/20"
]
```

you can create a sort with function inside:

```
array.sort(function(x1, y1) {
  x = x1.slice(-2);
  y = y1.slice(-2);

  if (x > y) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (x < y) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

Now if we console log we see:

```
"22/23"
"21/22"
"20/21"
"19/20"
"2019"
"2018"
"2017"
"2016"
"2015"
```

Now you have the concept, you can play with it and push it to the next level.

Comment: Could also use `<=>`, the "spaceship" operator

Comment: of course, I just try to make it so simple so possible to let OP understand it best posible.